# Change the size of scrollbar in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I want to change the size of the actual bar/thumb part of the scrollbar in winforms but I can't find a way to do this.  The thumb is about 1/10 of the actual scroll area regardless of how much there is to scroll.  It's the same whether I have to scroll down 1 line or 1000 line.  I want the size of it to adjust depending on how much there is to scroll or at the very least make it something like 50% the size of the scroll area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I got it. `this.vScrollBar1.LargeChange = this.vScrollBar1.Maximum / 2;` changes the thumb to half the track length.

Answer (score 4):

The from contains some property to adjust the scrolling such as: `AutoScrollMargin, AutoScrollMinSize, AutoScrollOffset`, and it also have `HorizontalScroll` and `VerticalScroll`, the last two properties represents the virtecal and horizontal scroll bar of the form, they also expose some properties like `Minimum, Maximum, SmallChange, LargeChange, Value..`, If using all those does not satisfy your requirements, then you should use a custom `Scrollbar`. Add `ScrollBar` to the form and disable the form scroll bar, and adjust your custom scroll bar whenever a controls added to form or changes its size...

Comment: Except don't ever use a custom scroll bar. When configured correctly, everything works as expected.

Comment: I don't want adjust the scrolling, I just want to change the length of the bar.  The part you drag on to scroll.  I want to change the actual vScrollBar control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar.aspx

Comment: @Jack: That is the thing, you can't access to the underlying bar directly, the form only exposes the `VertiaclScroll` property, but its type is `VScrollProperties` not the `VScrollBar`!. So if the predefined properties of that `VScrollProperties` and the other form properties can't help you. then you have no choice but to use a custom scroll bar.

Comment: But I do have access to the ScrollBar control directly.  I'm using a custom control from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/YLScsImagePanel.aspx which is made of a panel and a hScrollbar/vScrollbar.  VScrollBar and HScrollBar inherit from ScrollBar so if it works for ScrollBar it should work for those.  This is why I'm saying I want to change the actual vScrollBar control to do that but I don't know how.

Comment: Actually I got it.  `this.vScrollBar1.LargeChange = this.vScrollBar1.Maximum / 2;` changes the thumb to half the track length.

Answer (score 1):

The thumb bar size of a scrollbar control is directly proportional to the difference between that control's `ScrollBarName.Maximum`  and `ScrollBarName.LargeChange` values.

To make use of `ScrollBarName.LargeChange`a proportional offset value is needed for `ScrollBarName.Maximum`so that the scrollbar control when used behaves as intended. The following example demonstrates how this offset calculation is made and how it is applied in a practical application context.

**Offset Calculation:**

```vb
ScrollBarName.Maximum = MyMaximum + MyLargeChange - 1 ' LargeChange Usage Offset Calcualtion
```

**Application Context:**

```vb
'*** Using Simplified Values To Avoid Confusion ***

Dim ScrollBarName As New VScrollBar ' Or HScrollBar Control
Dim MyMaximum As Integer = 100 ' Your "off screen" calculated value
Dim MySmallChange As Integer = 10 ' MySmallChange <= MyLargeChange <= MyMaximum
Dim MyLargeChange As Integer = 50 ' MyLargeChange <= MyMaximum (Example produces thumbar sized {(MyLargeChange / ScrollBarName.Maximum) %} Clientsize.width
Me.controls.add(ScrollBarName) ' Add Your Control
ScrollBarName.Dock = DockStyle.Right ' Dock bottom for HScrollBar

ScrollBarName.SmallChange = MySmallChange
ScrollBarName.LargeChange = MyLargeChange
ScrollBarName.Maximum = MyMaximum + MyLargeChange - 1 ' LargeChange Usage Offset Calcualtion
ScrollBarName.Value = 20 ' The scrollBar movement value whereby ScrollBarName.Value <= MyMaximum
```